# Creating a Slackbot that adds

Tags: slack

Hey in my team's slack (messaging system for those who don't know) we have an automatic response, so that when anyone says "trump", slackbot automatically responds with "the wall just got ten feet higher". Now I want to make a counter that essentially allows slackbot to state "the wall just got ten feet higher, wall height:(have a updated value according to number of times "trump" has been stated)" So basically I want a way to have a value that updates the wall height but I am lost on how to do that within slackbot. Any help is much appreciated, thanks to all!

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not provide the solution you are looking for?

Comment: I am truly just wondering if there is an addition function within the slackbot auto response messaging system, more specifically when I am using the system the official slack team has provided I was wondering if there was a way to have a function within that response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @epluribusunum13 Sounds like you have some great questions for Google...

Answer (score 0):

The default features provided by Slackbot only allows it to respond to keywords, but not much more. So to provide that additional feature you would need to develop a custom bot.

For your use case I would recommend building a so called [internal integration](https://api.slack.com/internal-integrations) for Slack using the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api).

**Internal integration** allows you to add custom functions for your Slack team only (as opposed to a full fledged Slack app, that could also be installed and used for other Slack teams).

The **Events API** allows you to set up a bot that listens to messages and can react to keywords like "trump".

An alternative approach to the events API would be the [outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks). However this function is now deprecated and should no longer be used. Also it only works with public channels.

To set this up you will need to develop a small webservice (e.g. in PHP) that listens on a webserver for requests from the events API, keeps count of how many times the keyword has been invoked in the past and sends an appropriate message back to your Slack team every time the keyword is used.

I can recommend reading the excellent [official Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PHP this can be done easily using the [Slackbot Framework](https://github.com/iranianpep/slackbot). It supports [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) allowing you to listen to messages in channels or direct messages (depending on the permission scopes of your APP). So all the conversations on Slack can be sent to your server and you can search for the specific keyword in every message. Then send back an appropriate message to Slack. In summary, the first step is to create an APP for your slack team at https://api.slack.com/apps?new_app=1. Next step is to install the Slackbot Framework which is explained [here](https://github.com/iranianpep/slackbot/wiki/Getting-Started). Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That can also be done by integrating custom slack bot using Django. You'll have to subscribe events and based on events, Slack will send conversation message to the given url, and based on the event, you can write your logic to increase count and post message back to slack work space.